# SSH connection asking for password instead of key

Tags: ssh

Ok so i'm trying to connect from one server to another using SSH.

I have copied across the key from the 'client' machine to the 'server' using ssh-copy-id, it was still coming up with the password prompt so I checked the log in /var/log/secure and saw the "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory" error which I fixed using chmod on the user account's (non-root account) .ssh directory and files.

Now there is are no longer any errors reported in the /var/log/secure file, the -v log from ssh on the 'client' side shows the following:

```
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/identity
debug1: Offering public key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug1: Trying private key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

It then asks for a password to be entered... Selinux is disabled.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Stuart

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your permissions on the **.ssh** directory should be:

```
drwx------
```

On key files should be:

```
-rw-------
```

After you managed this, on server in your **.ssh/authorized_keys** append your public key used for authentication.

Also, names should be id_dsa* or id_rsa* for default ssh to work. If you have other names, use this:

```
ssh -i /path/to/mykey
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, yeah my .ssh is drwx------ and keys are -rw------- , the public key is also appended to the authorized_keys but still it isn't working. There are no errors in the log either!

Comment: Can you copy and past the command you're invoking? Maybe with **ssh -vvv user@server**

Answer (score 0):

Ok i've found what the issue was - turns out the user's .ssh directory was owned by root rather than the user itself. It seems that this doesn't trigger an "Authentication refused: bad ownership or modes for directory" error in the logs, which I find a little strange.